# Visualforce page loading fast from tab but takes long time when clicked button on it

Tags: visualforce

We have a Visualforce page to show some report data and we have created a custom tab for it. 
When we click on tab page loads faster and data renders quickly as we have called a function from constructor of VF controller.
However when we click command button on Vf page which again calls same function but it takes time to render data (too long time). Only difference is on page load contractor calls that function but from command button same function is directly called.

Answer (score 1):

Performance depends, in part, on the size of the view state size. When you load the initial page, there is no view state, so it loads quickly, but after doing stuff, your view state is larger, so the page moves slower. You can learn more about that in the [Order of Execution in a Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm) and its related pages.

Basically, to keep your page "snappy", you need to minimize your view state size. Consider using the [`transient`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) keyword on variables that are either part of the form and/or can be reconstructed based on available inputs. Without specific code, it's impossible to provide a specific path to optimization, but just keep in mind that you must have a small view state in order to have good page performance.